# websocket send to specific user nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am currently creating a websocket server for a mobile front. and in some cases I need to send a json only to a specific user and after several attempts I still haven't managed to get Websocket to work so I can send my json to one client at a time.

i'm using this library : github.com/websockets/ws

To explain my problem i have several products that contain several variables that need to be refreshed in real time. when a user connects to a product he will receive only the json of that product and the other users will receive the json of the other products they are currently on. that's why i want to send a specific json to a user to enable this

I would like to know if any of you know how to fix the problem as I'm starting to block on it.

Thank you very much.

````
const opp = new WebSocket.Server({port: 10001});
let user = 0;
let lookup = [];

opp.on('connection', function connection(op) {
    lookup.push(op.id);
    let id = "";
    op.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        id = message;
        query = {
            text: "SELECT id,state,users_list_name,user_win,timer_stamp FROM products WHERE id = " + parseInt(id) + " AND circle = 1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN state = \'available\' THEN \'1\' WHEN state = \'soon\' THEN \'2\' WHEN state = \'expired\' THEN \'3\' END",
        };
    });
    client.connect();
    const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
        client.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());
                console.log(query);
            } else {
                console.log(lookup);
               for (let i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++){
                    console.log("########################");
                    lookup[i].send(JSON.stringify(res.rows));
                }
            }
        });
    }, 300);
});```
````

Comment: Why does your title say socket.io, but your code uses a plain webSocket?  Which is it?

Comment: It was a mistake, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So, `lookup[i]` is going to be an `id` from `op.id`.  Is that really what you can send to?  Which websocket server module are you using so I can look at its API?  Also, the first sentence of your question still mentions `socket.io`.  I see you have corrected the title.

Comment: If you want to send the data to only the client that started this interval, then instead of looping through all the `lookup` array, just do `op.send()`.  That will represent the client that sent you the message that set the query that corresponds with this interval.

Comment: FYI, running a separate `setInterval()` on a 300ms frequency for every single connected webSocket is not going to scale at all.  You're database is going to fast become a bottleneck.  I don't know what problem you're trying to solve here, but you will need a different/better architecture that doesn't have every single client separately hitting your database every 300ms.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I would like to send to each customer without any further action on their part. I also need to send each of them an update of the information that makes up each product view in real time. the actual delay will be 1000ms and not 300ms.

Comment: Well, your question says: "I need to send a json only to a specific user".  So, your question does not describe sending the same JSON to every single user.  Plus, you are starting a SEPARATE `setInterval()` when every single client connects.  So, if you have 10 connected clients, then you have 10 `setInterval()` each banging on the database, each sending updates to all the clients.  This design doesn't make sense.  I think you need to back up and reword your question to describe EXACTLY what you're really trying to accomplish.  I'm too confused about what you're trying to achieve to help.

Comment: And, please answer my above question about which server-side webSocket library you are using?

Comment: i'm using this library : https://github.com/websockets/ws

To explain my problem i have several products that contain several variables that need to be refreshed in real time. when a user connects to a product he will receive only the json of that product and the other users will receive the json of the other products they are currently on. that's why i want to send a specific json to a user to enable this.

Comment: A couple questions.  What is this `lookup[i].send(JSON.stringify(res.rows));` suppose to do?  And, what is `op.id` in this `lookup.push(op.id);`?  I ask these questions because your code does not seem like it is written to do any of the things you say you want it to do.  So, I need to understand what you are trying to do with these lines of code.

Comment: It used to be a simple send command, but when I tried to figure out how to do a specific send, it was said that you had to store the user id to be able to use it via a send command.

specific and that's what I tried to do with the manipulations you mentioned.

lookup.push(op.id) was to store the id
lookup[i].send(JSON.stringify(res.rows)) was to send to specific ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  Still trying to understand the actual spec you're shooting for.  But, assuming the following (based on your answers to my prior questions):

1. A client connects using a webSocket.
2. When they send a message over that webSocket, that message is an `id` of something that can be looked up in your database and that they want regular updates for.
3. Those updates for that particular `id` should be sent only to that specific client that requested it.
4. If a different client connects and specifies some `id`, they should get updates for that `id` only.
5. When a client sends a new message that specifies a different `id`, their updates should now be only for that new `id`.
6. Updates for the `id` that one client requested are sent only to that one client (not to the other clients).

If that's what you really want, here's a way to structure that.

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 10001});

// make database connection that all users share
client.connect();

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    // these variables are unique to each ws connection
    let interval, query;

    // when webSocket closes, stop any current interval timer associated with this webSocket
    ws.on('close', function() {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });

    // when we get an id, start querying for updates on that id
    ws.on('message', function incoming(id) {
        console.log(`received: ${id}`);
        query = {
            text: "SELECT id,state,users_list_name,user_win,timer_stamp FROM products WHERE id = " + parseInt(id) + " AND circle = 1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN state = \'available\' THEN \'1\' WHEN state = \'soon\' THEN \'2\' WHEN state = \'expired\' THEN \'3\' END",
        };
        // if interval is not already going, start it
        if (!interval) {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                client.query(query, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log(query);
                    } else {
                        // send data to just the one client that this timer is for
                        ws.send(JSON.stringify(res.rows));
                    }
                });
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, some comments:

1. Polling the database on a short time interval with a separate polling loop for every single client simply will not scale at all.  You will have serious database scale issues.  You really need a better design here, but since we don't know the overall requirements and architecture of your application, we don't have enough info to know what to suggest.  Probably you want to leverage notifications in a database that tell you when data has changed rather than you polling it on a short interval on behalf of every single client.
2. I could find no reason for the `lookup` data structure.  Your comments say that you want to send updates to ONE specific client, the one that requested that id.  That can be done with `ws.send()`.
3. This code assumes that the `client` variable represents a connection to your database that each of the setIntervals for each connected client can all share.  That's why that code was moved out of the `wss.on('connection', ...)` event handler.
4. I switched to the more common terminology of `wss` to refer to the server instance and `ws` to refer to the webSocket for a particular connected client.
5. `ws.send()` is how you send to a connected client.  I still don't know what you were doing with `op.id`.  Looking at the doc for the `ws` library, that doesn't appear to be something you can use to send to.
6. Your code (and this code) creates a separate `setInterval()` timer for every webSocket client that connects and it uses a very short interval time.  This will not scale.  At worst, the interval time needs to be lengthened into multiple seconds (depending upon desired target scale).  At best, you need to stop polling the database entirely and use some other mechanism in the database for getting notifications when data has been changed.

Comment: that exactly what i'm trying to do, thanks for the time you spended on it . i'm new on nodejs so maybe i wasn't the most accurate in my responses, sorry for that.

thanks